# Spring WS SOAP Response transformation using XSL template file

Tags: spring, spring-boot, soap, spring-ws

I have a requirement where we need to apply transformation to the response of soap services using xsl file, currently using springboot 2.7

Tried to intercept the requests using EndpointInterceptor.handleResponse() method and applied transformation on the response but,transformation is not applied.